Responsive Image field
I re-created a website previously written with Drupal 8.9.20 using Drupal 10.3.0. The theme I used is Parallax Theme 8.x-1.8 in Drupal 8 and Parallax Theme 3.0.1 in Drupal 10. In both versions of the site I added to the "Basic page" content type an Image field, which is not to be shown in the published page. In Drupal 8 I have set the field as "disabled" in the "Manage Display" Tab and Drupal 8 allows me to save the format of image as "Responsive Image". Unforntunately with Drupal 10, adding the image field in "Basic Page", it's not possible to save the format as "Responsive Image" in the "Manage Display" tab if the field is disabled. Is there any solution or workaround to fix this problem? See attached screenshots. Thanks.

Usually if the field isn't to be rendered you'd handle the format its rendered yourself (whereever its getting used).
1 option is move the field out of disabled and then in the relevant twig template change {{ content }} to something like {{ content|without('field_image') }}
That will mean the field won't be rendered as part of the default content render in that template
